# Is there a common place for tips within SO to refer to?

Tags: discussion

There are plenty of questions around, actually requiring a link to a proved resource rather than in-place answers. I mean, to avoid dups, time waste and “omg, once again” reactions—we really need a place to store the best (aka verified) answers. E. g. I tried to find anything completely covering the *ruby buck-globals* and finally got stuck with writing my own [help-page](http://rocket-science.ru/tips/2013/02/26/ruby-predefined-globals/).

Well, I tried to do my best and I want to share it within SO-fellas. I’m sure that almost everybody have something to share as well. Is there no way at the moment or am I missing smth?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AlexanderR I am sure that the fewer people, the easier it is to resolve an issue. Let me start with ruby community.

Comment: @mudasobwa Very good point you raised here.

Answer (score 2):

> There are plenty of questions around, actually requiring a link to a proved resource rather than in-place answers.

Then they are not really questions suited for Stack Overflow. They should be closed as "not constructive" as per the faq (and numerous meta discussions).

About the duplicates, we already have a feature to close questions as duplicates, and it is currently being improved.

Finally, another place where interesting resources/links can be found are the tag wikis for many tags (e.g. [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby)).

Comment: We are living in an imperfect world. If everybody were conscientious enough to follow all the guidelines and faqs, SO would not be needed at all—each problem may be actually resolved without off-site help. The truth is that sometimes we got stuck with very stupid problems and SO may bring agile practices to alone programming. Furthermore, a question may be quite suitable for SO, while the real problem beyond is, say, “how to use map-reduce”. I ain’t to interfere SO rules, but since SO became a proven place to find solutions, I really want to attach kinda knowledge base to it.

Comment: You could also try chat for requesting links. The problem with them as answers is that after sometimes it tends to get out of control: lots of answers, many with broken or outdated links. The consequence is, the questions loses value in terms of being helpful for future users.

Comment: That’s exactly why I’m talking about SO-family hosted site for those.